# Hapi.js lab testing issue

Tags: node.js, hapi.js, hapi.js-lab

I am new to Hapi.js and node.js in general and am experiencing an issue when trying to code some tests.

Project structure:

[image]

When I run "npm test" i get the following output, how can I fix this?:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the `test` script in `package.json` to:

```
"test": "lab -c"
```